# Capacitor banks with opposite polarities

Tags: capacitor

How can the polarities be opposite?

[image]

Source:

Distribution Switchgear

Professor A.T. Johns

ISBN (10 digit) 0 85296 107 3

ISBN (13 digit) 978-0-85296-107-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is about AC distribution, so you can think of one wire as the neutral with 0V, and then the other wire is the phase wire which alternates between positive and negative.

If you plug in a capacitor to say 230VAC mains, and disconnect it at the moment of positive peak voltage, the capacitor stays charged to the +325VDC positive voltage. If you disconnect it at the moment of negative peak voltage, the capacitor stays charged to the -325VDC negative voltage.

So if you connect the capacitors now together, there is 650VDC voltage difference which will double the inrush current compared to say other being discharged to 0V and other having the full positive or negative 325VDC.